# Icon Color for different Status Angular 6

Tags: html, css, angular, angular6, less

I have a view on angular just like this :

[image]

This is my dashboard.component.ts

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  tablePresetColumns;
  tablePresetData;
 ngOnInit() {
  this.tablePresetColumns = [{id: 1,content: 'Username'},{id: 2,content: 'Status'}];
  this.tablePresetData = [[{id: 1,content: 'john.doe@random.com'},{id: 2,content: 'Busy'}],[{id: 1,content: 'test2@random.com'},{id: 2,content: 'overload'}]];
 }
}
```

And this is the way i call the table on dashboard.component:

```
<div eds-tile class="xl-4" style="height: 700px">
<eds-tile-title>User on Shift</eds-tile-title>  
<eds-table [columns]="tablePresetColumns" [data]="tablePresetData" [modes]="['compact', 'dashed']"></eds-table>
</div>
```

my eds-table :

```
selector: 'eds-table',
template: "<table class=\"table\" [ngClass]=\"modes\">\n  <thead *ngIf=\"columns\">\n    <tr>\n      <th *ngFor=\"let col of columns\">\n        {{col.content}}\n      </th>\n    </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr *ngFor=\"let row of data\">\n      <td *ngFor=\"let cell of row\">\n        {{cell.content}}\n      </td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table>\n",
```

And my question is, how should I do to make my view become at least just like this, I mean there are conditions when status Busy,

> Icon Color are green, or Idle are Yellow, and Overload are Red (in the right of the text):

[image]

Need support guys, thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below at `<td>`

```
<td *ngFor="let cell of row" 
  [ngStyle]="{'color': (cell.content === 'Busy') ? 'green' : (cell.content === 'overload') ? 'red' : (cell.content === 'idle') ? 'yellow' : ''}">{{cell.content}}
</td>
```

**OR**

with the below way,

```
<td [ngClass]="{
                'busy' : cell.content == 'Busy',
                'idle' : cell.content == 'Idle'
                'overload' : cell.content == 'Overload'
             }" *ngFor="let cell of row"> {{cell.content}} </td>
```

In  your css

```
.busy {
    color: green;
}

.idle {
    color: yellow;
}

.overload {
    color: red;
}
```

UPDATED ANSWER

```
   <td *ngFor="let cell of row"> {{cell.content}} 
      <span class ="dot" [ngClass]="{
        'dot-red' : cell.content == 'Busy',
        'dot-green' : cell.content == 'Idle',
        'dot-yellow' : cell.content == 'overload'}"></span></td>

.dot {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dot-red {
  background-color: red;
}
.dot-green {
  background-color: green;
}
.dot-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Hi @dileepkumar jami, i think it just give the color of my text into red,green, or yellow. Not icon in the right of text that i want

Comment: May I know which icon?

Comment: You want some icon next to the text?

Comment: yupp @dileepkumar jami, as my question and example pict above

Comment: i want to small round icon just like my pict above @dileepkumar jami

Comment: <i class="icon icon-alarm-level6 color-red"></i>

Comment: may I k now what are those icons?

Comment: i will try it my bro @dileepkumar jami

Comment: Hi @dileepkumar jami, if i want to move the icon more to the right, is it just edit the css ?

Comment: Hi @dileepkumar jami, i need your help. Why after i build my angular, the css seems wont load. But when i tried locally this works fine. Can you help me please...

Comment: No sir @dileepkumar jami, i've tried to build with ng build --extractCss=true, but it didnt mean anything. Css still wont load

Comment: i keep my css directory on /src/styles.css , my table template on node_modules/@eds/angular/fesm5/eds-angular.js